# How can you get a key event for from inside a button in javafx

Tags: java, javafx-8, keyboard-events

This is my code. When I run this program I get a normal scene, a normal pane, and a normal button. When I click the button in the top left corner, a circle appears in the coordinates: 450, 450 with a radius of 90 pixels. But when I try to move my circle by 10 pixels using my keyboard I see no change. Also I see no exceptions when I run my program.

```
    Pane p = new Pane();
    Button b = new Button("Clickable");
    Circle c = new Circle(450, 450, 90, Color.RED);
    c.setVisible(false);
    EventHandler<ActionEvent> e = s -> {
        c.setOnKeyPressed(g -> {
            if(g.getCode() == UP) {c.setCenterY(c.getCenterY() + 10);}
            if(g.getCode() == DOWN) {c.setCenterY(c.getCenterY() - 10);}
            if(g.getCode() == RIGHT) {c.setCenterX(c.getCenterX() + 10);}
            if(g.getCode() == LEFT) {c.setCenterX(c.getCenterX() - 10);}
        });
        c.setVisible(true);
    };
    b.setOnAction(e);
    p.getChildren().addAll(b, c);
    Scene s = new Scene(p, 900, 900);
    stage.setScene(s);
    stage.show();
    c.requestFocus();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think a node that is not visible can get keyboard focus; even if it can, when the user clicks the button, that will transfer keyboard focus to the button. You need to put the focus on the circle after the button is pressed:

```
Pane p = new Pane();
Button b = new Button("Clickable");
Circle c = new Circle(450, 450, 90, Color.RED);
c.setVisible(false);
EventHandler<ActionEvent> e = evt -> {
    c.setOnKeyPressed(g -> {
        if(g.getCode() == UP) {c.setCenterY(c.getCenterY() + 10);}
        if(g.getCode() == DOWN) {c.setCenterY(c.getCenterY() - 10);}
        if(g.getCode() == RIGHT) {c.setCenterX(c.getCenterX() + 10);}
        if(g.getCode() == LEFT) {c.setCenterX(c.getCenterX() - 10);}
    });
    c.setVisible(true);
    c.requestFocus();
};
b.setOnAction(e);
p.getChildren().addAll(b, c);
Scene s = new Scene(p, 900, 900);
stage.setScene(s);
stage.show();
```

It might be better overall, depending on your exact requirements, to register the event handler with the scene:

```
Pane p = new Pane();
Scene s = new Scene(p, 900, 900);
Button b = new Button("Clickable");
Circle c = new Circle(450, 450, 90, Color.RED);
c.setVisible(false);
EventHandler<ActionEvent> e = evt -> {
    s.setOnKeyPressed(g -> {
        if(g.getCode() == UP) {c.setCenterY(c.getCenterY() + 10);}
        if(g.getCode() == DOWN) {c.setCenterY(c.getCenterY() - 10);}
        if(g.getCode() == RIGHT) {c.setCenterX(c.getCenterX() + 10);}
        if(g.getCode() == LEFT) {c.setCenterX(c.getCenterX() - 10);}
    });
    c.setVisible(true);
};
b.setOnAction(e);
p.getChildren().addAll(b, c);
stage.setScene(s);
stage.show();
```

Comment: @user7341000 Please mark the answer as correct if it answers the question.